# Fitting a constant multiplier to a series to attain a specific sum at a specific length.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, fibonacci-numbers

sorry about the title.  I am not a math guy and the following question is way beyond me.

The following is for utility in a TSP solving algorithm I am writing.

I have a list of coefficients that I use while the algorithm is running, but under certain conditions I need to alter the list.  I need to alter it up to a specific point in the list, and the point is unknown until the condition is met.

So let's say I have a list, [.75, .75, .75, .75 ......], where each value is a coefficient for a certain iteration of my loop.  And then on iteration... say... 35, my algorithm determined I need to alter the coefficients.  I need to alter them up to the 35th entry in the list.

However, I want to alter them with the following conditions:

The 35th (or whatever the last entry was) needs to be bumped up by .1
Every other entry needs to be bumped up by some value, such that they form a series of [the fibonacci sequence] * C, where C is some constant that we can multiply every entry with such that the 35th(just in this example) number equals .1

So, yeah.  I have no idea how to do this.  It'd actually be nice to get some intuition on how to do this for any type of sequence, actually.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is not quite clear.  Could you give an example of a specific set (perhaps shorter than 35 terms) and the C value that does what you want? That would be a big help.

Comment: For a given number k, I want to be able to multiply each term from 1...n in the fibonacci series by a specific constant, and have the last term equal .1.

So for example, if k was 3, then constant C = .6 would get... kind of close, because:  0*.06, (1)*.06, (.6+0)*.06 would give a sequence of 0,.06,.096 - and it ends in a value that is nearly .1.

Comment: I'm still not clear.  Let me try an example. With k=5, we have the first 5 terms of the fibonacci sequence 1, 1, 2, 3, 5.  If I want the last one to equal 0.1, I need to multiply 5 by 0.02.  So I multiply all the terms by 0.02 to get 0.02,0.02,0.04,0.06,0.1.  I bet this isn't what you want.  Can you explain why? (I don't see terms of the fibonacci sequence anywhere in your example...).

Comment: Yours is actually correct, and mine isn't (it was late and I screwed up).

And hmm... it's actually this easy, huh.  Now I feel dumb.